# Chrome removes form tag in .innerHTML insert

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have some mvc frameworks that extend my .net application. Their task is mainly to deliver partials to the .net applications interface.

The funny thing is that chrome strips the very necessary

Here is how I fetch and render the data from the framework

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/mvc/UserProfile/AddressForm?datatype=shipping",
    dataType: "text", // text html script
    method: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {

        console.log(data);

        //var userProfileAdd = document.getElementById("userProfileAdd");
        var userProfileAdd = $("#userProfileAdd")[0];
        userProfileAdd.innerHTML = "<div>" + data + "</div>";
    }
});
```

Firefox, IE and so on does retrieve all data. Does anyone know why chrome behaves like this?

Thanks

EDIT

This is the code sent to the data variable printed by console.log

```
<script src="/scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form OnSubmit="return false;" action="/mvc/UserProfile/AddressFormPost" id="frmUserAddress" method="post"><div class="validation-summary-valid" id="validationSummary"><ul><li style="display:none"></li>
</ul></div>
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="8Vkd039Wc3825G6CTEomJ/aXfrCyjuEY3sV/ty4znHi9yO0Th535p8VNxqvBwhJ12AREQhvTMhRVNEO6Ke3O87jDAjREg3I3dFYp2Y5geutbEOLk6KHmn6hLb4a5CFaZ3uCOm8uYgr/U4au33yaUFw==" />


<div>
    Select country:
    <select id="Countries" name="Countries"><option value="029">Caribbean</option>
        <option value="AE">U.A.E.</option>
        <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="AL">Albania</option>
        <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
        <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    Postal Code
    <input class="formField textBox" id="PostalCode" name="PostalCode" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="PostalCode_validationMessage"></span>
</div>


<div>
    City
    <input class="formField textBox" id="City" name="City" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="City_validationMessage"></span>
</div>

<div>
    State
    <input class="formField textBox" id="State" name="State" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="State_validationMessage"></span>
</div>


<div>
    First name
    <input class="formField textBox" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="FirstName_validationMessage"></span>
</div>

<div>
    Email
    <input class="formField textBox" id="Email" name="Email" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" id="Email_validationMessage"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send!" id="btnAddressForm" class="button" />
</div>

</form><script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
if (!window.mvcClientValidationMetadata) { window.mvcClientValidationMetadata = []; }
window.mvcClientValidationMetadata.push({"Fields":[{"FieldName":"PostalCode","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"PostalCode_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"Please enter your postal code","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"required"}]},{"FieldName":"City","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"City_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"Please enter your city","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"required"}]},{"FieldName":"State","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"State_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"Please enter your state","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"required"}]},{"FieldName":"FirstName","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"FirstName_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"Please enter your first name","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"required"}]},{"FieldName":"Email","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"Email_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[{"ErrorMessage":"Please enter your first name","ValidationParameters":{},"ValidationType":"required"}]}],"FormId":"frmUserAddress","ReplaceValidationSummary":false,"ValidationSummaryId":"validationSummary"});
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have an example page online containing this code? This way we can test your code. Possibly your posted html isnt valid?

Comment: Can you also post the contents of userProfileAdd.

Comment: userProfileAdd is simply an empty div where I place the contents, <div id="userProfileAdd"></div>

Answer (score 8):

Chrome will strip out the form element if there is a surrounding form element.  JUST the form tag disappears, all of its contents remain.

Check to make sure that there isn't a parentNode for "userProfileAdd" that is a form.

Comment: Interesting, if I paste several forms at once (using `jQuery.html()`), it only strips the first form tag.

Comment: Like @Leksat said: This seems to be a buggy behaviour, and its still the case as of today.